# How to get a float value the pointer points to?

Tags: delphi, pointers, floating-point, delphi-2009

In my app, i've created the TList type list where i store the pointers to 1 string and 2 float(real) values for every 3 items.

```
aList.Add(@sName); //string
aList.Add(@x1); //float
aList.Add(@x2); //float
```

Then, i want to get the values out from the list, but i could only do that for string

```
sStr := string(lList.items[i]);
```

But i couldn't get the float values as `a := real(lList...)` will result in an invalid typecast error.

So what do i do to get the float values?
Of course i have a question if that string casting will actually give me the string value. I'm not good at pointer stuff so i don't know how to do it.

Comment: There is some data missing, but doing that kind of assignation can result in access violation. When casting a string to pointer, that won't increase it's reference count. So when sName goes out of scope, your pointer may becomes invalid. Same goes for your float values. When X1 and X2 variable get out of scope, the pointers aren't valid anymore.

As for the invalid typecast, you can do a typecast like this, you probably just forgot to dereference the pointer.  Double(lList[I]^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend that you create a record:

```
TMyRecord = record
  sName: String
  x1: Double;
  x2: Double;
end;
```

and then create a generic list of that type:

```
var
  MyRecordList: TList<MyRecord>;
```

and from there, you should be able to easily access your data in the list.

Trying to store data in a TList with specific data types in specific positions like that is way more trouble that it needs to be.

Comment: +1.  I was about to say the same thing, but Nick beat me to it.  You can find the generic TList in the `Generics.Collections` unit.  But it has some strange compiler quirks in Delphi 2009 and might not always work right.  If you have problems with it, I'd recommend upgrading to Delphi 2010, which is a lot more stable when it comes to generics.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Nick. But you can do what you're doing anyway.

If 'a' is of type 'Real',

```
a := Real(aList.Items[i]^);
```

or if 'a' is a pointer to a Real (^Real),

```
a := aList.Items[i];
```

for strings, store the address of the first element (of course you need to test for empty strings),

```
s := 'Hello World';
aList.Add(@S[1]);
[...]
s1 := string(aList[i]);
```

or use a 'PChar' and store the address where it is pointing to,

```
s := 'Hello World';
aList.Add(@s^);
[...]
s1 := PChar(aList[i]);
```